# Anyone with a solution to the Decorator dilemma in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I've read some of the various post explaining how to implement the decorator pattern in Ruby but they all seem to have a problem?  Here are the some of the links:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/evaluating-alternative-decorator-implementations-in

or ...

http://www.runtime-era.com/2013/10/quick-review-decorator-pattern-in-ruby.html

However they all seem to suffer from some inconsistencies with regards to the GOF standard on decorators.

Has anyone come up with a solution yet?

Comment: may be this question is for programmers.SE